# How do I prove that a curve is irreducible for the Euclidean topology?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, algebraic-curves

> Consider the polynomial $f(x, y) = y^2 - x^3 + x \in \mathbb{R}[x, y]$. I would like to check wether the curve $C = \mathcal{V}_f(\mathbb{R}) = \{(x, y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid y^2 - x^3 + x = 0\}$ is reducible or irreducible for the usual Euclidean topology.

I have already shown that it is irreducible for the Zariski topology, but I do not understand how to show this for the Euclidean topology. Can somebody give me a hint or explanation ?

Comment: In general, this notion of irreducibility does not apply in the Euclidean topology. For example, $\mathbb{R} = (-\infty,1]\cup[0,\infty).$ So it is the union of closed proper subsets. The real line is not irreducible, and similar would apply to whatever curve you want to consider. This definition is only useful in the Zariski topology, where open sets are dense.

Comment: In euclidean topology, there are hardly any irreducible sets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's disconnected:  the equation is
$$y^2=x(x-1)(x+1).$$
In any real solution $-1\le x\le 0$ or $x\ge1$. There are real
solutions for $y$ for any $x$ in these intervals, so falls into
two components, one defined by $-1\le x\le0$ and the other by $x\ge1$.

Answer (score 5):

No Hausdorff space with more than one point is irreducible.  Indeed, if $X$ is a Hausdorff space with two different points $x,y\in X$, there are disjoint open sets $U$ and $V$ with $x\in U$ and $y\in V$.  The complements of $U$ and $V$ are then closed sets whose union is $X$ and neither is all of $X$, so $X$ is not irreducible.

So to show a variety is not irreducible in the Euclidean topology, all you have to do is show it has more than one point, since the Euclidean topology is always Hausdorff.  I'll leave it to you to find two different points on your curve.